# Creating mail account wordpress Plug in

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, gmail

Is there any wordpress plug in that is capable of receiving mails and email like gmail or yahoo mai?.. A plug in ,in which dashboard is not necessary in sending and receiving emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is my go to https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/.
Once you install it go to Settings -> Email you can put in your smtp settings.
Don't have one? Set up a Gmail account an use theirs, here is a quick how to: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: Wordpress isn't in the business of being a mailbox. Gmail is a mailbox, Wordpress is just a CMS that can send and "save" emails. Send being a relative term to SMTP.